# Roboelectic not working says "AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file"

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm trying to run Robolectric tests in MacOS Sierra but it's throws this error:

> AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml".

I already set Edit Configuration → Working Directory to $MODULE_DIR$.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml
at org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest.validate(AndroidManifest.java:121)
at org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest.getResourcePath(AndroidManifest.java:469)
at org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest.getIncludedResourcePaths(AndroidManifest.java:475)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createAppResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:491)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getAppResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:483)
at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:73)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:433)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:240)
```

Comment: [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ADQlDDrvsQc2pON0tRUjY3ZHc)
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ADQlDDrvsQa1FIMDRSTHRGRmM)
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ADQlDDrvsQQlZERWRFZzMzcWM)
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ADQlDDrvsQb0hwZWVTME9zVGM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a Mac, or running a Linux machine, it's quite possible you've run into a bug where Android Studio does not set the working directory to the module being tested. To work around this, you need to edit the run configurations, Defaults -> JUnit and changing the working directory value to $MODULE_DIR$.

http://robolectric.org/getting-started/[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O48Lm.png)